# "Warning: Function components cannot be given refs" error while using Link in nextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

I am getting this error when in nextJs when I wrap an Image tag inside a Link tag :

```
<Link href="/">
   <Image src={logo} width={50} height={50} className="btn rounded-full bg-transparent" />
</Link>
```

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20434#issuecomment-750673138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that the element you passed cannot be used to forward a ref, so using any element that does allow that will work. Typically you'll wrap it in an `<a>` tag in this case. i.e.

```
<Link>
   <a>
      <Image />
   </a>
</Link>
```